# Gnome shell extensions not working in Ubuntu 21.04 different error check everywhere

Tags: gnome, unity-dash, 21.04, gnome-shell-extension, dash-to-dock

***Note:*** *Please read this carefully, i had googled a lot cant find any solution. I tried other answers too but they didn't worked for me* 
 *Thanks to everyone in advance...*

Some detailed information about my OS:

- Default Display Manager: gdm3
- - GNOME Shell Version: 3.36.9
- Ubuntu 21.04
- **gnome-tweak-tool** is installed
- **gnome-tweaks** (installed)
- **gnome-shell-extensions** (installed)
- **chrome-gnome-shell** extension is added to chrome
  I am trying from the past 2 days to use **Gnome Shell Extensions**. The problem is that these extensions aren't shown in **Tweaks** / **Gnome Extensions** after i am enabling them [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/) i also rebooted the system multiple times and also restarted the gnome shell multiple times but nothing is working. I aslo had tried multiple browsers including Chrome, Firefox, Vivaldi and added the **GNOME Shell integration** extension to them. 
   
  I tried to install them manually too (as explained [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etzAH.jpg)) but still nothing works. Also installed dash-to-panel extension: `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-dash-to-panel` [check this too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etzAH.jpg)

*I am apologising to everyone for anything i had done wrong, as i am newbie to the comunity as well as to Linux so i don't know too much*

```
[2]: https://www.debugpoint.com/2021/10/manual-installation-gnome-extension/
```

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2022-January/000276.html https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by restarting GNOME Shell.

Run the following command:

```
gnome-shell --replace &
```

Comment: As you said, i executed `gnome-shell --replace &` , after that i reopened this [page](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/) and i saw that the extension was **disabled** again.